# apache poi ppt issue with weblogic12.2.1.3

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, apache-poi, weblogic12c

I have a  code for generating excel and ppt. Excel file  is generating successfully but the problem is with ppt.It was throwing an exception "**Java.lang.illegalexception: schemas (*.xsb) for CTTable can't be loaded - usually this happens when OSGI loading is used and the thread context class loader has no reference to the xml beans classes**". This problem is causing only weblogic server.In local it was working fine.The following are the dependencies list.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Please recommend some suggestions .

Comment: @axel I added xmlbeans jar but same issue.and I checked dependency hierarchy of ooxml-schemas it was there like transitive dependency right still required to add it explicitly.and if I am adding any upper xmlbeans i.e 3.0.1 or . 3.0.2 it throwing new exception called nosuchmethoderror: xmloptions.setentityexpansionlimit.

Comment: Thanks for reply @axel I tried with 4.0.0 of poi and 1.4 of ooxml-schemas at that time also I faced the issue.if i am using xml beans  2.6.0 it was not throwing that issue, but rasing the issue that was explained in the post(schemas not loaded for CTTable).

Comment: Might be this OSGI issue: https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N1029C

Comment: Yes I seen that FAQ there it is saying that it supports OSGI with POI. need to include POIXMLTypeLoader.setClassLoader(....) ?? I placed that code after slide creation but no use can u me tell clearly.??

Comment: I do not have that issue. So I cannot test. But "The initialization should take place before any other OOXML" sounds to me not like "placed that code **after** slide creation". Instead it sounds like "place that code **before** any kind of `XSLF`, `XSSF` or `XWPF` class instantiation.

Comment: The FAQ entry is outdated, I.e. it's futile for the current release, as using the thread context loader is bad. The resources are now loaded on the schema class classloader, which should be bundled with .xsb files. For your issue: AFAIK weblogic brings its own XMLBeans version. Can you use the 4.0.1 dependencies and set the classloader order to parent-last?